# how to migrate the procedures b/w two databases in mysql

Tags: mysql

if i have 2 diff database(A&B),now i want to migrate all data (not only the tables, but also include the procedure) from A to B,is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few utilities that come packaged with mysql. Have you looked at mysqldump? It allows you to create a backup of a database which you can recreate elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

As Zach pointed out, mysqldump can handle this. If you would rather a GUI, you could also try [Toad](http://www.toadsoft.com/toadmysql/). It has a schema compare option that can show you the differences between the two databases and let you choose which tables and routines you wish to migrate.